# Does the ApplicationContextRunner in Spring Boot respect the bean initialisation order when using @AutoConfigureAfter on user configuration?

Tags: spring-boot

I have a unit test which uses the ApplicationContextRunner in Spring Boot 2.0.3.RELEASE.  The context runner is a field of my unit test class and initialised with multiple auto configuration classes.  In the body of my test method I use the withConfiguration method to add my target auto configuration class.  This auto configuration class is annotated with @AutoConfigureAfter.
Using the debugger it appears that the auto configuration class under test is initialised before the target of the AutoConfigureAfter annotation.

I've had a look at the context runner code and it would appear that the configurations are ordered by class name.

Is this expected behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[testing-auto-configurations-with-spring-boot-2-0](https://spring.io/blog/2018/03/07/testing-auto-configurations-with-spring-boot-2-0)

Having read the link above again, I've now realised my error.  I was using the withUserConfiguration in the unit test method.  This appears to be for user configuration classes and **NOT** AutoConfiguration classes.  If the autoconfiguration class is added to the context runner using withConfiguration(AutoConfigurations.of(TargetAutoConfiguration.class)) everything works as expected.